# "Can't access ViewModels from detached fragment" on interface onclick

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

I'm getting error "Can't access ViewModels from detached fragment" when onClick method implemented by AirportOnClickListener try do do anything with viewmodel (trigger event, set var etc). What's wrong with my code? I'm using hilt for DI
@AndroidEntryPoint
class SearchFragment @Inject constructor() : Fragment(), AirportOnClickListener {

```
@Inject
lateinit var adapter: RecyclerViewAdapter

private var _binding: FragmentAirportSearchBinding? = null
private val binding get() = _binding!!

private val airportSearchViewModel by viewModels<AirportSearchViewModel>()
private val args: SearchFragmentArgs by navArgs()


// recyclerview row click cause error "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't access ViewModels from detached fragment"
// when doing anything with airportSearchViewModel
override fun onClick(airport: Airport) {
    airportSearchViewModel.setAirportTye(AirportType.Origin) //ERROR
    airportSearchViewModel.triggerNavigation()  //ERROR
    Log.d("Selected airport", airport.name) //WORKS
}

class RecyclerViewAdapter @Inject constructor(private val airportOnClickListener: Provider<AirportOnClickListener>) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchViewHolder>() {

var list = emptyList<Airport>()
    set(value) {
        field = value
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): SearchViewHolder {

    val binding = RowAirportSearchBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)

    return SearchViewHolder(binding, airportOnClickListener.get())

}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return list.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SearchViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bind(list[position])
}
```

}

```
class SearchViewHolder(
private val binding: RowAirportSearchBinding,
private val airportOnClickListener: AirportOnClickListener,
) :
RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

fun bind(airport: Airport) {
    with(binding) {
        city.text = airport.city.name
        country.text = airport.country.name
        code.text = airport.code
        root.setOnClickListener {
            airportOnClickListener.onClick(airport)
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
@Module
@InstallIn(FragmentComponent::class)
abstract class AirportListenerModule {

@Binds
abstract fun bindClickListener(
    searchFragment: SearchFragment,
): AirportOnClickListener
```

}

```
    kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property airportSearchViewModel has not been initialized
    at com.jurgielewiczp.androidchallenge.views.search.SearchFragment.getAirportSearchViewModel(SearchFragment.kt:37)
    at com.jurgielewiczp.androidchallenge.views.search.SearchFragment.onClick(SearchFragment.kt:44)
    at com.jurgielewiczp.androidchallenge.views.search.SearchViewHolder.bind$lambda-1$lambda-0(RecyclerViewAdapter.kt:49)
    at com.jurgielewiczp.androidchallenge.views.search.SearchViewHolder.$r8$lambda$dVFh158DngIJuL9pfu4VOonhCvg(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.jurgielewiczp.androidchallenge.views.search.SearchViewHolder$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown Source:4)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6614)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6587)
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:787)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26122)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6831)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:927)
```

Comment: did you add `@HiltViewModel` on top of  `AirportSearchViewModel`?

Comment: @WSAyan i did it

Answer (score 3):

This happens to me because I was accessing a `ViewModel` field, that was stored as a field in the `Fragment`, before the `Fragment` could become attached to the `Activity` thus giving the error.

To fix this I *could've* explicitly accessed the `viewModel.myField` at the multiple places where it is needed.

**BUT**

Rather than making a call to the same "not so lightweight" Object, that isn't even guaranteed to be used during the screens user-session / life-cycle, due to how the app is used and what this specific Object is used for.

So, instead of recreating the same heavy object each time AND unnecessarily at the creation of the `Fragment` I decided to create it lazily because it's not guaranteed to be used and it's a heavier object so it's be a singleton as the `lazy` modifier makes the object a singleton by default.

**Example of the declaration:**

```
private val myCallback by lazy { viewModel.myStateCallback }
```

and then used the local variable accordingly.

Hopefully this will help someone!